# STM32F103C8T6 Bluepill - core held in reset error

Tags: stm32, reset, cortex-m0, write-protect

"Core is held in reset" - the error stm32 st-link utility tool throws when I try to erase my STM32F1 blue chip. Is my board damaged or something? In Settings Window - Under STM32 Target Information, Target and Target Voltage detection appears to be failed (in Normal and Connect Under Reset mode).

I selected Hot Plug Mode and the device was visible... then I tried to clear the chip but I got the error: "Internal Command Error", "Read Out protection is activated".

In Hot Plug Mode, I went to Option Bytes and disabled write protection. It didn't work.
I am using the Bluepill (it is possible it is counterfeit) and ST-Link V2 debugger (https://www.banggood.in/Geekcreit-3_3V-5V-XTW-ST-LINK-V2-STM8-or-STM32-Simulator-Programmer-Downloader-Debugger-500MA-Fuse-Short-Circuit-Protection-Aluminum-Alloy-U-Disk-Shell-With-20cm-Dupont-Wire-p-1177014.html?cur_warehouse=CN&rmmds=search). It's the small usb one. My connections are: 3.3V, SWIO, SWCLK and GND. The ST-Link is working fine as I have used the same st-link for stm32f0 dev board and it works fine.

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Have you got the 3.3V connected between MCU and ST-Link? In fact, you don't even mention how you have connected the two, so please add the info, how else would we know if it is wrong or right.

Comment: There are 4 connections required for the SWIM connector- GND/Vdd/Data/Reset. Are all properly connected? Can you try another module?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany SWIM is for STM8, this is STM32, so the ST-Link JTAG connector needs to be used for SWD. GND/VDD/SWDAT/SWCLK required at minimum.

Comment: @Justme Thanks for your comment. I will add that info. Pls see the updates in the post.

Comment: That's not a real ST-Link from ST, that is a clone so it may work differently, as clones may output 3.3V.

Comment: So does that means that the problem is not fix-able?